# DataGridView - Change BackColor of RowHeader on Click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to change the color of the row header in a data grid view after clicking.

```
private void DGV_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    var row = DGV.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    row.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    row.HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

However, the color is never changed?

Comment: [`EnableHeadersVisualStyles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.enableheadersvisualstyles?view=netframework-4.7.2) → false

Comment: I put `DGV.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;` in the constructor of the class but still no luck.

Comment: ...then the code you posted doesn't duplicate your problem.

Comment: @LarsTech, `BackColor` works while `ForeColor` not work. I will use BackColor then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show different color than the visual styles color, you need to set [`EnableHeadersVisualStyles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.enableheadersvisualstyles?view=netframework-4.7.2) of the `DataGridView` to false.

If you want row headers show a yellow background color when you select the row, you have a better option than handling click event of the row headers:

```
dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```